# Mapping using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hi I have a Jsp with 5 fields. The jsp has a button to add new employees. Employee ID, Employee Name, Employee Phone number, Employee Current Address, Employee Permanent Address

I have created two tables Employee and Address. The Employee table has columns `empid, ename and empPhno`. Address tables have fields `empCuAdd` and `empPerAdd`. I have created two classes for Employee and address. I have created two xmls for Employee and address `emp.hbm.xml` and add.hbm.xml to store values into the tables that are given the fields above. The objects of two classes are empobj and addobj.

Now I like to know how to store the values into two tables from the single jsp page. The button for adding new employees in the JSP, calls a function `addemployee()` in while I have given save(empobj).

The code is for following

The values from the jsp are stored in the form beans(EmployeeForm). The form is converted into EmployeeModel. **Here I have a doubt, should I maintain two forms from a single Jsp which has fields pertaining to EmployeeModel and AddressModel, that is taking values from the Employeejsp and storing to EMployeeForm and AddressForm**.

Now Passing the empmodel only stores the three jsp values. I like to know ho

```
public addEmployee(Employee empmodel)
{
    save(empmodel);//this is the method to save the object to the employee tables using hiberbate file(employee.hbm.xml)
}
```

But the save(obj) only stores the values of employee id, employee name and phone number. I just like to know how to save the values into two tables employee and address using the single jsp and a single save method, passing a single object.

**In short Could anyone explain, how can I store the values from a single JSP page into two tables using Hibernate. Some values in the jsp get store into one table and other values get stored into the second table. I am using Struts.**

Answer (score 0):

Use embedded and embeddable to store in single table... Define you address class as @EMBEDDABLE and you emp class as @EMBEDDED...(annotations are not caps letter)

Comment: Could you please explain me how to do the mapping of hibernate using xml